# Sorting an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am quite new to objects and I'm trying to sort the following example by 'name' without much success.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   [{
    "5be471e0-5970-11ea-8e53-3dcfba064c75": {
        "id": "5be471e0-5970-11ea-8e53-3dcfba064c75",
        "name": "Harold Wood",
        "job_title": "Manager",
        "employee_id": null,
        "created_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30"
    },
    "5c0346d0-5970-11ea-b49e-816916f41cbb": {
        "id": "5c0346d0-5970-11ea-b49e-816916f41cbb",
        "name": "John Smith",
        "job_title": "Developer",
        "employee_id": "104",
        "created_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30"
    },
    "5c03c180-5970-11ea-866e-f3f6da276a02": {
        "id": "5c03c180-5970-11ea-866e-f3f6da276a02",
        "name": "Paul Johnson",
        "job_title": "Engineer",
        "employee_id": "42",
        "created_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30"
    },
    "5c043f80-5970-11ea-bd7e-9fc0f189b2e0": {
        "id": "5c043f80-5970-11ea-bd7e-9fc0f189b2e0",
        "name": "Mary Runton",
        "job_title": "Clerk",
        "employee_id": "78",
        "created_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30"
    }
}]
```

Comment: What do you want to sort? You have an array with 1 object. Properties within the object are unsorted.

Comment: You've got an array with one object in it. If you want the objects in there sorted, you'll have to extract them into another array first. You can't control the ordering of properties in an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote it your array only contains one object which makes its sort unefficient.

First you'll need to have an array containing your objects this way (as your object keys are id values I just got rid of this redundancies):

```
 [{
    "id": "5be471e0-5970-11ea-8e53-3dcfba064c75",
    "name": "Harold Wood",
    "job_title": "Manager",
    "employee_id": null,
    "created_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c0346d0-5970-11ea-b49e-816916f41cbb",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "job_title": "Developer",
    "employee_id": "104",
    "created_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c03c180-5970-11ea-866e-f3f6da276a02",
    "name": "Paul Johnson",
    "job_title": "Engineer",
    "employee_id": "42",
    "created_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c043f80-5970-11ea-bd7e-9fc0f189b2e0",
    "name": "Mary Runton",
    "job_title": "Clerk",
    "employee_id": "78",
    "created_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-27 14:49:30"
}]
```

Then you could simply perform an `Array.sort()` using a function to sort based on `name` value

```
yourArray.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.name.localCompare(b.name);
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: Extracting the objects to another array solved it, thanks